# Does closing an InputStreamReader also close the underlying InputStream?

Tags: java

JavaDoc for `InputStreamReader` doesn't say anything about closing the underlying `InputStream`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#close--

> Description copied from class: Reader
>
> Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it. Once the stream has been closed, further read(), ready(), mark(), reset(), or skip() invocations will throw an IOException. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.

Does closing an InputStreamReader also close the underlying InputStream?

**UPDATE** In:

```
InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")
istream.close();
```

Do I need to close `conn.getInputStream()`?

`InputStreamReader` implementation direct `close` call to `StreamDecoder` which is a native class.

Comment: Yes. Which stream do you think "the stream" is referring to otherwise?

Comment: @AndyTurner I think you'll find it doesn't close it.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou the `InputStreamReader`  will close the `StreamDecoder` that close the `InputStream` link to it. See [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/InputStreamReader.java#InputStreamReader)

Comment: @AxelH & AndyTurner You're both right. I had got confused.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou it depends what you mean by "close". I mean that `InputStreamReader.close()` calls the `InputStream`'s `close()` method; what that does is quite irrelevant to the `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: "any system resources associated with it" is kind of a hint, and refutes the "doesn't say anything" claim.

Comment: As a point of interest, by comparison, it seems that the Javadoc for java.util.Scanner is clearer and more explicit: "When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface." On the other hand, the Javadoc for InputStreamReader.close() is just a copy from the interface Reader.close(). There are other Readers too. The Javadoc for StringReader.close() also says "Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it." This is for a Reader on a String. What is this stream it's talking about?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As other answers and comments said, the answer is yes, it does close the InputStream. You can see for yourself with the following code:

```
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("D:\\a.txt");
    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(is);
    r.close();
    is.read();  // throws exception: stream is closed.
```

Therefore, if you close the Reader, you don't need to also close the InputStream. However, I guess you are using try-with-resources everywhere (aren't you? ;) ) and the InputStream as well as the Reader will both be closed at the end of the try block. That doesn't matter, because an InputStream can be closed multiple times; it's a no-op if the stream is already closed.

If you want to avoid closing the InputStream, you can write a simple wrapper that does nothing when it is closed:

```
    class UncloseableInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
        public UncloseableInputStream(InputStream is) {
            super(is);
        }
        public void close() {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("D:\\a.txt");
    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(new UncloseableInputStream(is));
    r.close();
    is.read();  // still works despite closing the reader.
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on stream implementation. `InputStream` is just an "interface" in terms of `close()`. `InputStreamReader` will not close an interface. It will close the underlying data resource (like file descriptor) if it is. It will do nothing if `close` is override and empty in an implementation.

In OpenJdk `StreamDecoder` has a method

```
void implClose() throws IOException {
    if(this.ch != null) {
        this.ch.close();
    } else {
        this.in.close();
    }
}
```

`this.in` is a InputStream from decoder constructor:

```
StreamDecoder(InputStream var1, Object var2, CharsetDecoder var3) {
    ...
    if(this.ch == null) {
        this.in = var1;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Here are examples of closing actions. `ByteArrayInputStream`:

> Closing a ByteArrayInputStream has no effect. The methods in this class can be called after the stream has been closed without generating an IOException.

```
public void close() throws IOException {
}
```

`FileInputStream` differes:

> Closes this file input stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream. If this stream has an associated channel then the channel is closed as well. After you closed the underlying instance it doesn't matter which interfaces were using it, it will be closed.

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    synchronized (closeLock) {
        if (closed) {
            return;
        }
        closed = true;
    }
    if (channel != null) {
       channel.close();
    }

    fd.closeAll(new Closeable() {
        public void close() throws IOException {
           close0();
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: "InputStream is just an interface." I wish that were true. It's not.

Comment: Can you prove you statement? Official docs ambiguous unfortunately and implementation goes to native code that makes check hard to complete...

Comment: `InputStreamReader.close()` invokes `close` on the `InputStream`. It's no concern of the `InputStreamReader` if the `InputStream` ignores that call.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd it terms of `close` it is just an "interface". What will exactly happen depends on implementation.

Comment: @AndyTurner You say from your own experience or have prove for your statement?

Comment: @gavenkoa [look in the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/InputStreamReader.java#199).

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin it's an abstract class, not an interface

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd it doesn't matter. Default close implimentation is empty